# Sorting 18-digit numbers

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm going to sort 18-digit numbers like 100930200153461004, 100930200153461004 etc. It's nearly about 20K numbers to be sorted out. Which methods or ways can I use to make this happen fast. I'm using C#.net.

Thanks.

Comment: try Array.Sort in C#

Comment: Pick any classic O(n . log(n)) algorithm and you should not be able to measure the time taken to sort 20 000 different 64-bit quantities.

Comment: "Fast" is very subjective. Try this - load them in to an array in memory as strings (padding with leading zeros, if necessary) and then do `var mySortedList = myLoadedList.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();`. If it's fast enough then you're done. if not then try a variety of well published algorithms until you either give up or find one fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

18 digit numbers should fit in a Int64. Just put them all in a List and call List.Sort().

20K numbers to sort isn't a lot really. Using the standard Sort() will already try to optimize the sorting algorithm depending on your input, no need to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of sorting methods. I would say sorting is not related to any language like C# or php, but before you implements it in any of your computer language. Have a good study of how the different sorting algorithms works. See the link - http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/
thanks